# How can I download an image that has no source (local image)

Tags: python

So I understand how I can download images from the web, in which they have an 'src' but now I am trying to access images that I have already downloaded on my computer, making changes to it, and then downloading it to my computer again.

```
from PIL import Image

redish = Image.open('gradient_red.jpg')
check_pics = open('pictures','wb')
check_pics.write(redish)
check_pics.close()
```

I tried doing the same thing as one would download images with an 'src', but it does not work because the object is not a 'byte-like object'

Comment: Please post the code you tried that did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "downloading again", when the image is already on your computer?

Comment: So I have the image on my computer, now I am trying to crop it then re-downloading it, and the code I have there is the code that I tried

Comment: Is the python program running on your local PC? Then there is now "downloading". You are trying to open a file on your computer. Does the file with the name "gradient_red.jpg" lie in the same folder as your python script's working directory? If you do `import os
print(os.getcwd())` in your code, it should print the local working directory. If your image file is not in that directory, you have to provide the full file path when you open it!

Comment: @Kidus Asmare Ayele this is not "downloading". "Downloading" means to transfer from a remote computer to your local computer. You want to open a file, change it and then save it (in the same file or a different one). Make sure the file is there and readable and maybe provide the full path.

Comment: Okay mb for not making it clear but it is in the same folder, the error is that this is not a byte-like object since I am trying to write 'redish' in bytes to a file

Answer (score 0):

So I just found out that PIL library has a method called 'save'. I just had to do this.

```
from PIL import Image
redish = Image.open('gradient_red.jpg')
redish.save('test.jpg')
```

Thank you all for helping